# select data from database, using c# parameter for it

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, select

Please can you help me why my command for select dont select any data. I try change select from name to ID and it works but i need that this select work for name select not nly for ID.

**Database data:**

```
id      user      password      level
1       Rad3k       .....         0
```

**Script for select:**

```
public bool loginVerification(string name, string password)
{
    test = name;
    bool access = false;
    string checkLogin, checkPassword;
    int level;

    commandS = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.users WHERE user like @name", conn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        commandS.Parameters.Clear();

        // Parameters
        SqlParameter nameParam = new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
        nameParam.Value = name;
        commandS.Parameters.Add(nameParam);
        commandS.Prepare();
        SqlDataReader reader = commandS.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                if (reader.IsDBNull(i))
                    return access = false;

            checkLogin = reader.GetString(1);
            checkPassword = reader.GetString(2);
            level = reader.GetInt32(3);

            if (name == checkLogin && hashPassword.ValidatePassword(password, checkPassword) == true)
                access = true;
        }

        return access;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

**If i use this select so it works:**

```
commandS = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.users WHERE id = 1", conn);
```

**But when i use this so it dont work:**

```
commandS = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.users WHERE user like @name", conn);
I try use this without parameter, but it dont work too.
commandS = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.users WHERE user like 'Rad3k'", conn);
commandS = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.users WHERE user like '%Rad3k%'", conn);
commandS = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.users WHERE user like 'Rad3k%'", conn);
commandS = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.users WHERE user = 'Rad3k'", conn);
// and same with paramter still dont work
```

Thanks for all people which can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a plain SQL statement, you would use

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.users WHERE user like '%Rad3k%'
```

You need the `%` to match a substring, without them it would mean a full match (only user 'Rad3k' would be found). Note that you could also use `like 'Rad3k%'` for a "starts with" match.

From C# with parameters, it would be

```
commandS = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.users WHERE user like '%' + @name + '%'", conn);
```

Answer (score 1):

your command should be like this

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.users WHERE user like '%" + @name + "%'"
```

Comment: like `'%" + @name + "%'"` no ?

Comment: @Ehsan not at start of like ... ;) Anyway, just a detail !

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus i initially posted this thing. Then i edited incorrectly. And then i reverted.... Thanks.

Comment: Syntax and code is correctly and it works in DB but not from C# still find nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need use `like` operator when you are filtering against `strings`:

```
 SELECT * FROM dbo.users WHERE user like '%" + @name + "%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set value to passing parameter using `AddWidthValue` :

```
SqlParameter nameParam = new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
commandS.Parameters.AddWidthValue("name", name);`
```

Comment: Problem is that, I try use select with parameter and without parameter and from C# it find nothing. only when i select id it work. I dont knwo why.

I try this directly. select * from dbo.user where user like '%Rad3k%' - it find nothing from C# and when i try this so too nothing: commandS = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.users WHERE user like '%' + @name + '%'", conn);

Comment: edit your query and try
commandS = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.users WHERE user like %@name", conn);

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work. You can use like operator without %. If you want an excact match on user you can just use user = @name.

Are you sure that you dont have any additional column in that row that are null?
This code dismisses all rows with an null column:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            if (reader.IsDBNull(i))
                return access = false;
```

Try to comment out these lines and test your code.

Comment: i think that this is not problem because now i have in table only one row with name Rad3k as i say. This code only for future for more datas. But i trying commented it.

Comment: Yes, but the code above checks for columns with null. So of there are any columns in the 'Rad3k' row that are NULL, it will return false. I tested your code on my demo data and it worked fine.

Comment: i commented it, but i have still same problem. I dont know where i make fail

Comment: Ok, try to run the query in SQL Server Management Studio and see if the query works there. Also try to debug your code to see where it fails?